# Why do many "popular" C++ libraries have a small number of stars on Github?

Tags: c++, libraries, github

For example a [CSV parsing library](https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser) looks to be the [most popular CSV parsing library](https://github.com/search?l=&o=desc&q=csv%20parser%20language%3AC%2B%2B&ref=advsearch&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93), yet it only has 301 stars.

C++ is one of the most popular languages yet C++ libraries on github do not look to be very popular?

I realise that some of it is due to C++ being more difficult then many other languages. On the other hand a CSV parser is something which is likely to be one of the most frequently used tools (especially among scientific computing community).

Why do C++ libraries have so little stars on Github?

Comment: There is a wide, wide chasm between people that use stuff, some of which might be on github, and people who rate libraries.

Comment: @whatsisname With Github's dominance in opensource projects it's fair to say that the number of stars is a good proxy for the number of users. That is, it is very likely that between X-Y%  of users of any project give them stars.
What other metrics allow you to assess popularity (e.g. tags on SO)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with software engineering and is purely speculative.

Comment: C++ is a minority language. https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017 Also, because C++ code base has a high up-keep cost (both in actual cost and in skilled labor cost), only certain companies can afford to have a sizable C++ code base. These tend to be large companies which are adverse to open source. Sharing C++ programming tips are okay; sharing or using actual open-source code in production systems may need to get through several layers of approval.

Comment: This is sort of a "sociology within computer programming occupations" question. To accurately research and portray the "causes", careful studies and experimentations are needed. Otherwise, the answers that are offered (such as on a site like this, where none of us have sociology training), are merely speculations or "observations from a sample size of one". Also these hypotheses would be disorganized - they would contradict each other; nobody can piece together a complete picture from anecdotes.

Comment: Different ecosystems are differently star-happy on GitHub. You are going to see a lot more stars per project in “hip” areas like web dev, JS, or Ruby. Some people use stars as bookmarks, as an endorsement, or to indicate that they use this library. But there's no clear correlation between number of stars and number of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ users are much less likely to reuse libraries than users of other languages.

Most other popular languages have a package manager which makes it really easy to add libraries. Typically there is a standard repositories of packages for your language, and you just add the ones you need to your project. In contrast, C++ lacks any such standard package manager.

In addition, C++'s more complicated model makes reusing code difficult. You have to worry about matching compiler flags, adding include/library paths, and linking to the right libraries. Many other popular languages don't have to deal with the same baggage as C++.

Thus while a Ruby/Python/Rust/Java/etc coder will look for a library to reuse when they need new functionality, a C++ coder will be resistant to adding a new library and will most likely try to roll the functionality from scratch.

See, for example, this question on parsing CSV in C++:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Versus response for Java:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274259/read-csv-with-scanner

The C++ question had several implementations offered to him. The Java version had several posters chiding the OP for attempting to roll their own parser.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that C++ requires more domain experts to achieve a solution? I get the idea of rolling your own customised solution, but how many areas (algorithms, networking, hardware) can developers truly say that they are an expert in? So to confirm, there are fundamental reasons why C++ cannot be reused compared to languages such as Rust (which are almost as performant)?

Comment: The missing module system might be a reason. But far worse I think is the amount of "glue code" that (sometimes) is necessary when libraries use non `std` classes.

Comment: @Greg, not perhaps "fundamental" reasons. If a C++ package manager/build system became popular it could make it easy to reuse code and might reverse some of the trend.

Comment: @DanielJour, I don't see (immediately) how C++ has any worse of a glue problem there than other languages.